# Error when exporting archive file or file system with Eclipse (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to export my project in order to reuse the code into a new project.
Every time I try to export it, both "file system" and "archive file" I get error

```
Problems were encountered during export:
  Error exporting name_of_my_project/bin/jarlist.cache: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/name_of_my_project/bin/jarlist.cache'.
    Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/name_of_my_project/bin/jarlist.cache'.
```

Maybe it depends on the fact that I copied file into my project folder without using Eclipse.
Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: I did it several times but i had the same problems. I restarted my computer and eclipse, i refresh once again and now it works. thank you sir :D
What's the right way to import a full project to reuse the code? I exported the project as "file system" and then i imported it into a new project. I have no error in eclipse, but if i run my app, it crashes, without giving me error on logact

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Eclipse, right click on the project and click `Refresh`. This will have Eclipse resync the project with the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on that particular project
2. Click **Refresh**
3. That's it

Now: Do the export and it will work like a charm. Sometimes when you manually copy projects into the workspace, like I did, you encounter syncing problem. Refreshing the project re-sync it with the file system.

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided here did not fix my situation. I believe the issue started with updating eclipse. I was not able to export the file system after updating Eclipse.

Fixed it by taking my project file in my local git repository and moving it to another folder for a backup.

I then shared my project in eclipse by right clicking project -> team -> share project. Select the location of my repository and clicked finish.

My updated project was now located in my local repository and  was able to export the file system with no errors.